# Laravel Eloquent Many-to-Many?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I need help writing a query in eloquent that first searches for a city in the zipcodes table then uses those ids it found to then find activities that exist in that list of zipcodes.

Tables:
Zipcodes
- id (which represents zipcode)
- city

Activities
- id
- name
- zipcodes_id (which ties to the zipcodes table)

Never mind I finally figured it out.

```
        $zipcodes = Zipcodes::has('activities')->where('city', '=', $city)->get();
        foreach ($zipcodes as $zipcode)
        {
            echo $zipcode->activities;
        }
```

Returns:

```
[{"id":1,"activity_type":2,"name":"Four Peaks Grill & Tap","zipcodes_id":85032}]
```

Comment: The Laravel Docs have a good example of how to get going with Many-to-Many relationships: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I finally figured it out.

```
$zipcodes = Zipcodes::has('activities')->where('city', '=', $city)->get();
foreach ($zipcodes as $zipcode)
{
    echo $zipcode->activities;
}
```

Returns:

```
[{"id":1,"activity_type":2,"name":"Four Peaks Grill & Tap","zipcodes_id":85032}]
```